# Format of xml file for android XMLParser

Tags: android, xml

I am using XMLParser to parse xml file from server. I was wondering in xml file it is neccessory to put

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

or just

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

will work.

My server xml file is of below format and it is not working properly.

the log file out is

```
http://pastebin.com/MjcgW1pG
```

This is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<application> -<catalog> -<currency id="1"> <rate>1.5</rate> <type>Euros</type> </currency> -    <currency id="10"> <rate>1.5169</rate> <type>USA$</type> </currency> -<currency id="16">     <rate>1.4901</rate> <type>AU$</type> </currency>  </catalog> </application>
```

Comment: If, as you say, "it is working properly", I'm not sure why you're asking the question. Are you worried that at some point in the future it will stop working? Java, by default, uses UTF-8 for strings so as long as your server continues to return XML as UTF-8 encoded, there won't be a problem. If, however, your server returns XML data using any other encoding then you'll need to take that in to consideration.

Comment: @Squonk - it is good to ask what the guarantees actually are as often code works by cooincidence and then starts failing when a change occurs. In this case the code works by meeting a standard and so should not break - except there are clients out there which make false assumptions.

Comment: Sorry it was it is not working properly. miss spelled.

Comment: @mann - we need to see more - what do you mean by not working - as I note there should be no difference

Comment: @Mark http://pastebin.com/MjcgW1pG this is log output

Comment: That log does not tell us what is wrong or the XML - put it in the question

Comment: @Mark http://pastebin.com/eB4fDfH5 here is cat log output

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those are strictly required as they are the default encoding an version in XML. As in the [XML 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#sec-prolog-dtd) says

> .... is an XML 1.0 document because it does not have an XML declaration:

However I think it is better to put the explicit values so everyone is clear what the values are. So start with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: Thats alright but my question was my xmlParser is not working correctly so are you sure this can be reason (or one of the reason) for that